# Fitting a pdf against Weibull pdf

Tags: curve-fitting, mixture-distribution, density-function, method-of-moments

I have a pdf function as follows:
$$\dfrac{1}{s+a-b} [bs e^{-bt} + (a-b)(s+a)e^{-(s+a)t}]$$
I want to fit this against a weibull pdf with shape=1.12 and scale=461386. I want to calculate the values of s,a and b. Is there any standard tool for doing this?

Prasenjit

Comment: Have you searched the Web for "Moment matching"?  [This hit](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~osogami/thesis/html/node29.html) looks perfect.

Comment: Can I ask what the motivation for using this particular "approximation" is? Are you familiar with the relationship between a Weibull and a single exponential?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I want to approximate a system with Markov chains. That's why I need to approximate weibull

Answer (score 5):

**Moment matching** is a standard tool.  Whether it works well needs to be determined.  The mean $\mu_1$ and the next two central moments $\mu_2$ and $\mu_3$ of this mixture-of-exponentials PDF are

$$\eqalign{
\mu_1 &= \frac{\frac{s}{b}+\frac{a-b}{a+s}}{a-b+s} \\
\mu_2 &= \frac{b^2+s (2 a+s)}{b^2 (a+s)^2} \\
\mu_3 &= \frac{2 \left(1+\frac{-a^3+b^3}{(a+s)^3}\right)}{b^3}.
}$$

Equate these with the corresponding moments of the Weibull distribution (which equal $442626$, $1.56725 \times 10^{11}$, and $1.04716 \times 10^{17}$, respectively) and solve.  The general solution is a little messy but easy to compute:

$$\eqalign{
s &= \frac{4 \mu_1^3-6 \mu_1 \mu_2+\mu_3 \pm \sqrt{-2 \left(\mu_1^6-3 \mu_1^4 \mu_2+9 \mu_1^2 \mu_2^2-9 \mu_2^3\right)+4 \mu_1 \left(2 \mu_1^2-3 \mu_2\right) \mu_3+\mu_3^2}}{\mu_1^4+3 \mu_2^2-2 \mu_1 \mu_3} \

a &= -\frac{2 \left(\mu _1^3-3 \mu _1 \mu _2+\mu _3\right)}{\mu _1^4+3 \mu _2^2-2 \mu _1 \mu _3} \

b &= \pm \frac{2 \mu _1^3- \mu _3-\sqrt{\left(4 \mu _1^3-2 \mu _3\right){}^2-24 \left(\mu _1^2-\mu _2\right) \left(\mu _1^4+3 \mu _2^2-2 \mu _1 \mu _3\right)}}{\mu _1^4+3 \mu _2^2-2 \mu _1 \mu _3}

}$$

(Notice that all the denominators are the same.)

The two solutions differ by interchanging $b$ with $a+s$, as would be expected from the symmetry in the pdf: they are two distinct parameterizations of the same pdf.

The solutions for this particular Weibull distribution turn out to be $a = 1.72179 \times 10^{-6}$ and either (i) $s = 2.49314 \times 10^{-6}$, $b = 2.88012 \times 10^{-6}$ or, equivalently, (ii) $s = 1.15833\times 10^{-6}$, $b = 4.21493\times 10^{-6}$.  In the figure, the blue line shows the PDF of the Weibull distribution and the red line shows the mixture-of-exponentials fit:

[image: PDFs]

The distributions look a little different for small values.  Here is a magnified version near 0:

[image: PDFs]

The mixture of exponentials just cannot reproduce the behavior of a Weibull distribution in this range.  If the fit will be used to assess probabilities in the right tail, though, we might be ok.

Another natural way to compare two distributions is by the vertical deviations between their CDFs:

[image: CDFs]

At this scale, the two look coincident: this is good.  To appreciate the differences better, look at the differences between the two CDFs (fitted minus actual):

[image: Residuals]

They never differ by more than +0.006 or less than -0.003.  Therefore, when using the CDFs to compute probabilities of any interval, the results will never be wrong by more than 0.006 - (-0.003) = 0.009, less than 1%.  The differences in the right tails apparently go to zero, indicating the fit ought to be very good for right tail probabilities.

Comment: I admit I only very quickly skimmed your post, but isn't the fact that the differences in the right-tail converge to zero tautological? Would it be more appropriate to look at, e.g., the absolute relative error?

Comment: Wow I am deeply impressed. I was so reluctant to do this computation!

Comment: @Cardinal You are right about the (almost) tautological nature of that right-tail remark.  I didn't want to get into this, but the next step in this investigation would be to look at the ratios of the CCDFs, especially if the distributions were to be used to compute p-values associated with large values of the variable.  I also skipped over any discussion of having to check that the estimated values of $s$, $a$, and $b$ actually define a distribution--there's a question as to whether it is positive everywhere.

Comment: @whuber: See my first remark to Elvis's answer regarding determining whether the parameter estimates define a proper distribution. They are necessary and sufficient. :) (+1).

Comment: @Cardinal That's why I didn't discuss the issue :-).  Cheers.

Comment: This does give a valid pdf. Using the first set of parameter values you provide, we have $\lambda_2/(\lambda_2-\lambda_1) = (s+a)/(s+a-b)$ and $\pi = s / (s+a-b)$. Clearly $\pi < \lambda_2/(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)$, so the conditions in the comment are satisfied.

Comment: One last quick remark: I'm (quite) sure you've already noticed this, but it's immediately apparent from the survival functions of the exponential and Weibull that the approximation of the latter by a mixture of exponentials must be arbitrarily bad in the right tail (in a relative sense) except for the trivial case when the shape parameter of the Weibull is one.

Comment: @Cardinal Yes, by observing the Weibull is a power transformation of an exponential, we get a sense of just how much the tails differ.  But whether this is "bad" depends on how the distributions will be used.  I have been curious as to why one would attempt to approximate a Weibull with an exponential mixture (having a strange parameterization at that), but to provide a constructive answer to the question I decided to accept this and provide only a cursory assessment of the discrepancies that (inevitably) arise in the approximation.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning to mention the relationship between a Weibull and exponential in my last comment (not so much for you, as potentially future readers), but forgot. I fear the OP is unlikely to return, as I tried to request some explanation from the OP regarding the choice of approximation, apparently to no avail. (Also, just to clarify, I meant "bad" in a certain quantitative sense that you can easily guess, and not so much in a qualitative, more colloquial, sense.) Thanks for a stimulating answer. I also enjoyed @Elvis'.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for your answer. How did you solve this complex equations to get s,a,b ?

Comment: @prasenjit: It's algebra: nothing trickier than the quadratic equation.  A symbolic algebra system will make short work of it.

Comment: @whuber: Can you slightly elaborate on this ?

Comment: You should prefer using a more symmetric formulation in which $\mu_3$ is halved and $a+s$ is replaced by another variable, $c$.  The three fractions are all in the form $(-a^j+b^j+c^j)/(b^j c^j)$, $j=1,2,3$.  They are homogeneous of degrees $-j$.  This suggests looking at linear combinations of monomials that have degree 1.  The simplest such involving all three $\mu_j$ is a combination of $\mu_1^3$, $\mu_1 \mu_2$, and $\mu_3$; the second simplest involves $\mu_1^4$, $\mu_1 \mu_3$, and $\mu_2^2$.  From these you can obtain $a$ and from that, derive solutions for $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 2):

### Mixture of exponential distributions

*This answer is only partial, as it deals mainly with mixture of exponentials, which is only a part the proposed distribution family (cf infra) and comments*

**Edit: Added title, part 2 (EM algorithm for minimizing Kullback Leibler divergence) and 3 (numerical application)**

All this answer has been inspired by a previous state of vinux’ answer who suggested to use EM algorithm.

**1. Mixture of exponentials**

First this remark: this pdf can be re-written as a mixture of exponential distributions.

The pdf is 
$$f(t) = \dfrac{1}{s+a-b} [bs e^{-bt} + (a-b)(s+a)e^{-(s+a)t}],$$
which can be rewriten as a mixture 
$$f(t) = \pi \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 t} + (1-\pi) \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 t}, $$
where
$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
\lambda_1 &=& b \\
\lambda_2 &=& s+a \\
\pi &=& {s \over s+a-b} \end{array}$$
or equivalently
$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
a &=& (1-\pi) \lambda_2 + \pi \lambda_1  \\
b &=& \lambda_1 \\
s &=& \pi (\lambda_2-\lambda_1) \end{array}$$

All this for $t\le 0$; for $t<0$, $f(t)=0$.

This is a much more natural way to write it (even allowing "improper mixtures" with $\pi < 0$ or $\pi > 1$).

As an advantage, the moments of the exponential distributions are known, and now computing the moments of this distribution is straightforward.

**2. Adaptation of EM algorithm**

In the case of a proper mixture, we adapt EM algorithm to the minimization of the Kullback Leibler divergence, or equivalently to the maximization of
$$\int_0^\infty \log \left( f(x)\right) g(x) \mathrm d x,$$
where
$$g(x) = \left({k\over \lambda}\right)\left({x\over \lambda}\right)^{k-1} e^{ -\left({x\over\lambda}\right)^k} $$ is the Weibull density ($\lambda = 461386$ and $k=1.12$).

I don’t give details, I think those who know EM will recognize it...

a. Initialization. Start with $\pi^{(0)} = 0.5$, $\lambda_1^{(0)} = 1$, $\lambda_2^{(0)} = 2$, and $i=0$.

b. E-step. Let 
$$\tau^{(i)}(x) = { \pi^{(i)} \lambda_1^{(i)} e^{-\lambda_1^{(i)} x} \over \pi^{(i)} \lambda_1^{(i)} e^{-\lambda_1^{(i)} x} + (1-\pi{(i)}) \lambda_2^{(i)} e^{-\lambda_2^{(i)} x} }.$$

c. M-step. Let
$$\lambda_1^{(i+1)} = \left( { \int_0^\infty \tau^{(i)} (x) x g(x) \mathrm d x \over \int_0^\infty \tau^{(i)} (x) g(x) \mathrm d x}\right)^{-1},$$
$$\lambda_2^{(i+1)} = \left( { \int_0^\infty (1-\tau^{(i)} (x)) x g(x) \mathrm d x \over \int_0^\infty (1-\tau^{(i)} (x)) g(x)\mathrm d x}\right)^{-1},$$
$$\pi^{(i+1)} = \int_0^\infty \tau^{(i)}(x) g(x) \mathrm d x.$$
(Note that linearity of integral leads to straightforward simplifications of the expression of $\lambda_2^{(i+1)}$.

d. Increment $i$ and go back to the E-step, until convergence.

**3. Numerical application**

The above integrals are surely computable exactly, however I use numerical integration below; this will make the analogy with classical EM clear.

```
EMexp <- function(x, pi=0.5, lambda1=1, lambda2=10, ite=100)
{
  N <- length(x);
  Nmu <- sum(x);

  for(i in 1:ite)
  {
    f1 <- lambda1*exp(-lambda1*x);
    f2 <- lambda2*exp(-lambda2*x);
    tau <- pi*f1/(pi*f1+(1-pi)*f2)

    stau <- sum(tau);
    staux <- sum(tau*x);
    lambda1 <- stau/staux;
    lambda2 <- (N-stau)/(Nmu-staux);
    pi <- stau/N;
  }
  return(list(pi=pi, lambda1=lambda1, lambda2=lambda2));
}

k = 1.12
lambda = 461386

N <- 1e6;
x <- qweibull( seq(0,1,length=N+2)[2:(N+1)], k, lambda)
```

The we do:

```
> EMexp(x, 0.5, 2e-6, 3e-6);

$pi
[1] 0.5085704

$lambda1
[1] 2.259258e-06

$lambda2
[1] 2.259258e-06
```

The two components collapse, it seems that (from the point of view of KL divergence) a mixture of two exponential distributions don’t approximate this Weibull better than a single exponential distribution does (I tried with several starting points, it always converge here). This deserve to be checked by a theoretical approach, however I have no time now.

Comment: I don't believe you last "note" about $f(t)$ is true. Indeed, assume that $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$. I believe it should be relatively easy to show that as long as $0 \leq \pi \leq \lambda_2/(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)$, then $f(t)$ is still a valid pdf even though this includes values of $\pi > 1$, for which $f(t)$ is an "improper" mixture.

Comment: @cardinal Yes, you’re right, I’m sorry. I erased this note and modified slightly the remaining of the text... Is this notion of "improper mixture" known?

Comment: Nothing formal, that I can think of off-hand, but that doesn't seem surprising as it lacks the nice probabilistic interpretation when $\pi \in [0,1]$. (Note also, you use "cdf" in at least a couple of places where you mean "pdf".)

Comment: Yes I am not familiar with those abbreviations, I'll correct that, thank you @cardinal

Comment: I might also write $\int g(x) \log f(x)$ instead of $\int \log f(x)g(x)$ to avoid potential confusion. Cheers.

Comment: That’s right, or add parentheses – I’ll do that because for me this is the natural order to write this, the density $g(x) \mathrm d x$ at the end.

Comment: @cardinal to be clear: because for me it is natural to see the KL divergence as the expected value of the log likelihood $\log f(X)$ where $X$ has density $g$.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me (though, of course, as you know, the KL divergence includes an additional term, which is irrelevant to the development in your answer). :)

Comment: @cardinal Hum, yes, I wrote that last comment too fast! Many thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This pdf is a mixture of two exponential distribution. Maximum likelihood estimates of parameters will be difficult. The suggestion is

For quick solution use method of moments procedure. First three moments of this pdf equate with weibull moments.

Comment: (1) is a good solution, but I don’t get (2). EM is a likelihood maximization algorithm; what likelihood would you maximize here?

Comment: Standard mle procedure for mixture distribution is very complicated. EM is very efficient to estimate the parameters of mixture distribution. In EM, assume a  latent variables that determine the component from which the observation originates. So make the likelihood simpler.

Comment: I know EM. What likelihood do you suggest to maximize? There ain't no data.

Comment: I missed that part. Only method of moments make sense. I am changing my answer.

Comment: Thinking it well, you could use a variant of EM to minimize Kullback Leibler divergence between the two distributions... This looks like a cool idea.